# AVAudioPlayer too loud

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I've implemented AVAudioPlayer into my iPhone app but the audio being played is far too loud. To quieten the sound slightly, I changed the volume to 0.2f to see if it would have any effect. The volume stayed exactly the same. Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Blip.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
[audioPlayer setVolume:0.2f];

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog(@"Whoopsies, there was an error with the sound!");
else
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Why won't this turn the volume down?

Can somebody explain how I can?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code:

```
[audioPlayer setVolume:0.2f];
```

with following code:

```
    audioPlayer.volume = 0.2;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Give this a try just replace yours with this, maybe it has something to do with usage on NSURL instead of NSString

 NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Blip"];
 NSString *source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"mp3"];
 if (audioPlayer) {
  [audioPlayer stop];
  audioPlayer = nil;
 }
 audioPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: source] error:NULL];
 audioPlayer.delegate = self;
 audioPlayer.volume = 0.2;
 [audioPlayer play];

Answer (score 0):

As explained in Apples [*Audio & Video Coding How-To's*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/_index.html): You can't set the hardware volume.

> **How do I access the hardware volume controller?**
>   Global system volume, including your application's volume, is handled
>   by iPhone OS and is not accessible by applications.

The volume of an `AVAudioPlayer` instance is a relative volume. You can play two sounds with two `AVAudioPlayer` instances and set their volume relative to each other.

**EDIT:**

If you want to control the global volume of your device, you can use [`MPVolumeView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
MPVolumeView *myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:mpVolumeViewParentView.bounds];
[mpVolumeViewParentView addSubview:myVolumeView];
[myVolumeView release];
```

Comment: So how can I play a sound at a certain volume - different from the hardware volume? Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Other apps such as TweetBot do it?

Comment: I guess a [`MPVolumeView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will help you.